# Bootstrap Date picker Display only Specific month

Tags: jquery, html, date, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to get only Financial Year (i.e: July 2017) and format should be like this ( `2017-07-01/ yyyy-mm-dd` ) from bootstrap datepicker is there any way to do such task?.

I've searched a lot but I'm unable to get such results, and most important in calendar I want to restrict users not to select other months except July from 1st datepicker and June from 2nd datepicker.

Comment: Please create a working snippet, that way it will improve our chance of helping you

Comment: <img src="https://ibb.co/buWNmF" width="100" height="100">
here is my image i have shown a calendar in which i can select any month but i want restrict months and want to select only one month that is June

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also do with using the default date for months like this

```
var today = new Date();
var startDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
var endDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 6, 31);

$("#example1").datepicker({
 format: "MM yyyy",
    minViewMode: 1,
    autoclose: true,
   startDate: startDate,
   endDate: endDate
});
```

Check this

Comment: Thank you very much but it is showing dates as well all month but i only want to show months and all months should be disabled except one month (July)
Here is an example link http://jsfiddle.net/RWY2X/31

Comment: check the updated answer and if it solve the problem please accept it

Answer (score 2):

Modify the `dateFormat` attribute. You can also remove the date part of the selector by using relative selectors.

```js
$("#example").datepicker({
  changeYear: true,
  defaultDate: new Date(2017,5,03),
  dateFormat: 'MM yy',
  showButtonPanel: true,
  stepMonths: 0,
  onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
     console.log(selectedDate);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="example" />
```

Comment: Thank you dear, I've tried same but its not working, i want to enable only one month that is june and esle all month should be disabled.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RWY2X/31/ here is an example, i can select all months in this example but i only want to enable only one month .ie: June

Comment: I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = $(".date");
$input.datepicker({
      format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
      defaultViewDate: {year:2000, month:0, day:1}
    });
 $input.datepicker("setDate", null);
```

suppose there is an input element with class date,
now you are setting defaultViewDate year 2000 month january day 1
after that, setDate null will deselect the date, now you are at january month calendar without any selected date.

Answer (score -1):

Use these cdn files:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $( "#month,#month1" ).datepicker({
        inline: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: -20,
        maxDate: "+5M +1D"
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

**viewMode**: "months" displays only months and
**minViewMode**: "months" prevent to go years

```
$('#id').datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        viewMode: "months",
        minViewMode: "months"
    })
```

Comment: How does your answer compare to other answers? You should also add details explaining why your solution works.

Comment: viewMode: "months" displays only months and minViewMode: "months" prevent to go years.